# INSERT LLAVES FORANEAS MYSQL

Tags: mysql

tengo una consulta sobre Mysql, resulta que debo hacer un insert en la tabla, en esta hay un par de llaves foráneas, pero no debo insertar valores la primera vez sino que quiero dejar esos campos ocultos al usuario porque después el administrador llenará esos campos. Pero en el insert de usuario recibo este error, y es que la llave no debe ir vacía

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé que solución me recomiendan, agradezco si alguien me ayuda.

Comment: Si no podes agregar datos ahi, entonces no deberian ser claves definidas en la base de datos, porque la misma te esta diciendo que no pueden quedar vacios esos campos... O agregas datos dummy, o sacas esas referencias que realmente no te estan sirviendo...

Comment: Si, es que estas llaves luego el admin debe de colocar el estado y asignar un dato que el usuario no debe ver

Comment: ok.. pero nada te obliga a declararlas en la base de datos. Eso es solo una ayuda que da ese motor, pero en tu caso no te esta ayudando, te esta impidiendo trabajar. Saca esa restriccion y listo...

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: Pon nullables esos campos y no quites las llaves foráneas, aquí hay una respuesta parecida https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366854/can-table-columns-with-a-foreign-key-be-null

Comment: Si, asì lo hice, puse campo nulo alinsertar y luego se rellena. Gracias, me sirvió!

Comment: @OmarAlvarado ponelo por favor traducido como respuesta...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas poner los campos como "nullables", no es necesario quitar las llaves foráneas, estas fallarían sólo si intentas ingresar un valor diferente a null pero que no corresponda con los valores foráneos.

```
CREATE TABLE parent_table (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(255) NULL
);

CREATE TABLE your_table (
    id INT NOT NULL, 
    parent_table_id INT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_table_id) REFERENCES parent_table(id)
)
```

En el insert puedes especificar el valor NULL

```
INSERT INTO your_table (id, parent_table_id) VALUES (1, NULL);
```

Referencia:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366854/can-table-columns-with-a-foreign-key-be-null

Comment: gracias amigo, me sirvio